# "We're on our way" in a particular context

Tags: phrase-meaning

In some video lecture I heard that the lecture talked about the sequence of actions like do something, then do something another and then do something strange... and *we're on our way*. What does *we're on our way* mean here? I'm sure it has nothing to do with walking using our legs.

Comment: [To be on one's way](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/be-on-one's-way) - Oxford Dict.

Comment: If you are on your way, you have started your trip somewhere.   ⇒ He has been allowed to leave the country and is on his way to Hawaii.

Comment: @CopperKettle The context has nothing to do with journey. It was a techincal lecture about programming. That's way I'm not sure about your explanation

Comment: I guess it will mean different things in different contexts. You probably should add more context.

Comment: The phrase could be used to refer to a metaphorical trip: we're on our way to an answer or to a solution. It's basically impossible to *guess* what the speaker meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context you've described people use that phrase to mean:
After finishing these steps you can now use the item or product or whatever it may be.

An example for programming might be explaining all the steps to get your IDE installed and configured and then saying "and now we're/your on our/your way." Meaning now you can use it and move on to writing code.